# Validation (): Element 'xxx' is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error in aspx page and I found a solution for this. I'm getting this error for each tag I used in the page.

Computer -> OS (C:) -> Users -> {username} -> AppData -> Roaming -> Microsoft -> VisualStudio -> 9.0 folder. In this we have to delete "ReflectedSchemes" folder. But I don't have access to this path.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You copy that path and try to open it in command Prompt

```
explorer C:\users\Mydocs\blahbalah
```

Comment: What exactly u getting?

Comment: When I try to open the path in cmd prompt. It says "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

He its working fine for. check whether u are in root directory (if not type

```
 cd /
```

in ur cmd and then run this command

```
explorer C:\users\Mydocs\blahbalah
```

please make sure u are entering it properly